# PHP Remove string between [:en] [:]

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, qtranslate-x

How can I remove string from between square brackets and the brackets themselves with regex?

Let me clarify, is not that case: [some text] but this one:

```
Lorem ipsum[:en]Some text[:]
```

After "str_replace" the variable should contain just:

```
Lorem Ipsum
```

Someone can help me? I'm going crazy :)

Comment: $string = "Lorem ipsum[:en]Some text[:]"; $newString = explode("[",$string); echo $newString[0]  which is equivalent to  "Lorem Ipsum";

Comment: @marco Add your expected output.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: Sorry @VaibhaviSojitra and Toto, i'm new to Stackoverflow. The expected output is just ' Lorem Ipsum', next time i will explain better my problem!

Comment: @macro see my answer demo link

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove between [] from string.

```
 $str = "Lorem ipsum[:en]Some text[:]";
   $new_str = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`',' ',$str);

   echo $new_str;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Lorem ipsum Some text
```

[DEMO](https://paiza.io/projects/BM0mPleRSOHt0gaHRN6kgg?language=php)

Comment: What about multiple tags like in `Lorem ipsum[:en]Some text[:] Lorem ipsum[:en]Some text[:] Lorem ipsum`

Comment: No, it doesn't. It keeps only the first part.

Comment: I have also tried please check demo here https://paiza.io/projects/BM0mPleRSOHt0gaHRN6kgg?language=php

Comment: There are multiple issues with this. First of all, you probably have missed a `.` before the `*`, so I think it should be: `'~\[[^\]].*\]~'` now as @Toto pointed out, it's greedy therefore it will change "Foo [:en]Bar[:] Baz [:en] Foobar[:]" to "Foo" instead of "Foo Baz". Plus it would also change "Foo [bar] baz [bar]" to "Foo", while it should only work with `[:XX]...[:]`

Comment: if i add  `.`  before the `*` it is returning only first value. you can check in demo link @wawa

Comment: Ah, now I understand, what you're doing. I think you misunderstood his question. Your regex would turn "Lorem ipsum[:en]Some text[:]" into "Lorem ipsum Some text ", while he's looking for "Lorem ipsum" as result, He wants to remove everything which is between `[:en]` and `[:]`

Comment: oh.. okay @wawa

Comment: Code posted in answer doesn't work, but the code in Demo link works fine! You missed a `.` before `*`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
\[.+?].+?\[.+?]
```

**Explanation:**

```
\[      # openning square bracket
.+?     # 1 or more any character, not greedy
]       # closing square bracket
.+?     # 1 or more any character, not greedy
\[      # openning square bracket
.+?     # 1 or more any character, not greedy
]       # closing square bracket
```

**Code:**

```
$text = 'Lorem ipsum[:en]Some text[:] Lorem ipsum[:en]Some text[:] Lorem ipsum';
echo preg_replace('/\[.+?].+?\[.+?]/', '', $text);
```

**Output:**

```
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `~\[:\w{2}\].*?\[:\]~` as your regex.

**Code:**

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum [:en]Some text[:] dolor [:en]sit amet[:]";
$new_str = trim(preg_replace(['~\[:\w{2}\].*?\[:\]~', '~\s\s+~'],[' ', ' '], $str));
echo $new_str;

// besides running the regex, this also takes care of multiple whitespaces and whitespaces at the begin and end.
```

It will transform `Lorem ipsum [:en]Some text[:] dolor [:en]sit amet[:]` to `Lorem ipsum dolor` It will only match whats between `[:XX]` and `[:]` (where `XX` are two alphanumeric characters). This means, `Lorem [foobar] ipsum [baz]` will stay as it is and not be changed (as I guess, this is what you're looking for.

**Examples:**

```
Input: "Lorem ipsum [:en]Some text[:] dolor [:en]sit amet[:]"
Output: "Lorem ipsum dolor"
```

```
Input: "Lorem ipsum[:en]Some text[:] dolor[:en]sit amet[:]"
Output: "Lorem ipsum dolor"
```

```
Input: "Lorem [foobar] ipsum [baz]"
Output: "Lorem [foobar] ipsum [baz]"
```

[See it in action!](https://paiza.io/projects/Vie32MYH8fQuWuL3T9_4vA?language=php)

**Explanation:**
[`\[:\w{2}\].*?\[:\]`](https://regex101.com/r/bPicbC/1)

```
\[    # matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
:     # matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
\w{2} # matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
  {2} # Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times
\]    # matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)
.*?   # matches any character (except for line terminators)
 *?   # Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
\[    # matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
:     # matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
\]    # matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)
```